# Vscode says "package org.apache.pdfbox.preflight does not exist" even though I imported it

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have attached a photo of my code and the error that I am receiving. There isn't the red underline so I am not sure why it cannot find the package.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syh4Y.png)

````
import org.apache.pdfbox.preflight.Validator_A1b;
                                  ^
Validator.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Validator_A1b.main(new String[]{"xml", "/Users/ainscore/hms-hbs-reports/reports/2018/aicad/HMS_AICAD_print.pdf"});
        ^
  symbol:   variable Validator_A1b
  location: class Validator```
````

Comment: Delete the import sentence and hover over the `Validator_A1b`, use `Quick fixs` to import the needed jar. Is there any differences? Also can you share the download link of used jar for me to reproduce your question?